# Setting the form action content issue in Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony-3.1

This is my controller:

```
 /**
     * @Route("/contact/", name="contact").
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $contact = new Contact();

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($contact)
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('test'))
            ->getForm();

        return $this->render('contact/content.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
    /**
     * @Route("/contact/test/", name="test").
     */
    public function testAction(){
        echo 1; exit();
    }
```

This is my view:

```
    {{ form_start(form, {
                    'attr': {'id': 'contact-form'},
                    'action': path('test'), 'method': 'POST'}
        ) }}
                    <div class="text-fields">
                        <div class="float-input">
                            <input name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" type="text">
                            <span><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="float-input">
                            <input name="mail" id="mail" placeholder="e-mail" type="text">
                            <span><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="float-input">
                            <input name="website" id="website" placeholder="website" type="text">
                            <span><i class="fa fa-link"></i></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="comment-area">
                        <textarea name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="submit-area">
                        <button type="submit" name="contact-submit" id="submit_contact">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                            Send Message
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="msg" class="message"></div>
     {{ form_end(form) }}
```

When i press the submit button in the console from firebug this url is generated:

```
http://localhost/myproject/web/contact/contact.php
```

Can someone tell me ,from where did `contact.php` appear ? I should this url instead:

```
http://localhost/wb-builder/web/contact/test
```

Comment: it seems you have some routing problem coming from a wrong server configuration (apache or nginx). PS: remove the trailing slash on "contact" route.